# Is there any callback for network disconnect during request in curl

Tags: c++, ios, curl, libcurl

I am using libcurl to do the network request in the iOS, the timeout has been set to 60 seconds using option `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`. When the network is disconnected during request(`curl_easy_perform (curl)`), this call will not return until the timeout is reach after 60 seconds.

I checked the callback in the curl document, but didn't find an appropriate one.

Is there any callback I could register to detect the network disconnect during the request? So I could interrupt the request directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If libcurl knows that the connection is broken, then it'll return a failure for the transfer. When libcurl doesn't know that the connection is broken, it can't do anything about it and it has to wait for a timeout.

This is also explained further in the curl FAQ entry [Why doesn't curl return an error when the network cable is unplugged?](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Why_doesn_t_curl_return_an_error)